# How to get back parent with empty

Tags: parent, groups

I have a big empty parented to all my model, There are several small empty for window door etc. I forgot to select the small empty and parent to big empty. What i did is i selected my complete model and the big empty and parented. Now when i try to clear parent the big empty is separated but the small empty not link or not parent to the empty, I want to get that small empty back to work, Any suggestion.

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbmGM.jpg)

Comment: if you want the small empties to be children, select an empty then Shift G > Type and it will select all the empties, select the big one at the end to make it active and Ctrl P to parent

Comment: @moonboots: I think he knows it now ;) i think he wants them back because he unfortunately deleted them by parenting all to the big empty ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure to understand the initial question actually  ^^

Comment: @moonboots I know i can parent the small empties to big, but when i was parenting i forgot that, And the small empties are available but they do not work, If i remove parent from the big also the small are now individual working not like parent before they used to like group.

Answer (score 2):

I think then you have "destroyed" all your "little" empties functionality because every object can only have one parent. If you "overwrite" the parent with your "big empty" (because you assigned your model/objects to this) the "small" empties are not assigned anymore and useless.

I hope you have an older version from autosave which you can reload. If you didn't save, maybe CTRL-Z (undo) will help you.

Comment: It long time i have saved, No more ctrl+z will work, I dont have autosave also now,  Yes it destroyed all my little empties. Any other suggestion,